# Unable to trigger elif/else conditions in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program, and am having an issue with the following section:

```
device = input("Is the device a pump/compressor or a turbine: ")


Work_pump = mdot*(hout-hin)
Work_turbine = mdot*(hin-hout)

if device == "pump" or "compressor":
    print("Pump/compressor work rate =  ",Work_pump/1000," kW")  # significant figures should be addressed
elif device == "turbine":
    print("Turbine work rate = ",Work_turbine/1000," kW")
else:
   print("Device invalid, input in lower case")
```

I am unable to trigger the elif and else statements, even if the condition of `device == "turbine"` is met.
Is it just a minor syntactical issue?

Comment: Change `device == "pump" or "compressor"` to `device == "pump" or device == "compressor"`, or perhaps to `device in ("pump",  "compressor")`.  What you have now is equivalent to `(device == "pump") or "compressor"` which of course is always true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a minor issue. Change

```py
if device == "pump" or "compressor":
```

To

```py
if device == "pump" or device == "compressor":
```

If you want to not have to deal with capitalization, you can use `device.lower()` like

```py
if device.lower() == "pump" or device.lower() == "compressor"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if device == "pump" or device == "compressor":
    # significant figures should be addressed
    print("Pump/compressor work rate =  ",Work_pump/1000," kW")  
elif device == "turbine":
    print("Turbine work rate = ",Work_turbine/1000," kW")
else:
   print("Device invalid, input in lower case")
```

is the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight mistake:

```
if device == "pump" or "compressor":
    print("Pump/compressor work rate =  ",Work_pump/1000," kW")  # significant figures should be addressed
```

to

```
if device == "pump" or device == "compressor":
    print("Pump/compressor work rate =  ",Work_pump/1000," kW")  # significant figures should be addressed
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing the same test would be:

```
if device in ("pump", "compressor"):
    print("Pump/compressor work rate =  ",Work_pump/1000," kW")  # significant figures should be addressed
```

This is especially handy if the number of different device types gets larger; you could have pre-defined constants so you don't end up repeating the same lists over and over:

```
if device in DEVICES_PUMP_GROUP:
    ...
elif device in DEVICES_TURBINE_GROUP:
    ...
```